# How to prove the existence of divisorial Zariski decomposition?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $L$ be a pseudo-effective divisor, we may define its numerical fixed part $N_{\sigma}(L)$. How to prove it is a divisor? I know there is a proof in Nakayama's book, but I can't find this book.

Comment: $N_{\sigma}(L)$ is a divisor by definition so it is not clear what you think needs to be proved.

Comment: How to prove there are only a finite number of prime divisors $\Gamma$ such that $\sigma_{\Gamma}(L)>0$

Comment: Just a note: the book of Nakayama to which I think you are referring seems to be freely available from [Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.msjm/1389986103).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, you first define $\sigma_\Gamma(L)$ for big divisors and then you take the limit.

In other words, if $L$ is big, then clearly $\sigma_\Gamma(L)$ is non zero for only finitely many divisors. Indeed, $L=A+B$ with $A$ ample $\mathbb Q$-divisor, and $B\ge 0$. Thus $\sigma_\Gamma(L)>0$ implies $\Gamma$ is contained in the support of $B$.

If $L$ is pseudo-effective, then you define 
$$\sigma_\Gamma(L)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \sigma_\Gamma(L+\epsilon A)$$
where $A$ is ample (it is easy to check that the definition does not depend on the choice of $A$).

It follows that if $\sigma_\Gamma(D)=\alpha>0$ then $D-\alpha\Gamma$ is pseudo-effective. Finite generation of $N^1(X)$  implies  that there can only be finitely many $\Gamma$ with such a property.

Comment: How do you know that they remain a finite number when you pass to the limit?

Comment: I added two lines of explanations... let me know if it is clear. 

Comment: I reckon that to show the last assetion of your answer you need to use that if the $\Gamma_i$ are prime divisors such that $\sigma_{\Gamma_i}(D)>0$, then the numerical classes of the $\Gamma_i$ are linearly independent in the vector space $N^1(X)$. Am I wrong? 
This is what Nakayama does in his book. 

Comment: That is correct. 

Comment: This is correct. The finite generation of Neron-Severi group gives it.

Comment: Actually I don't see it so trivially. Of course $N^1(X)$ is finitely generated, but how do you see that the $\Gamma_i$ (I'm using the notation of my previous comments ) are not linearly dependent?
This requires some effort in Nakayama's book, I cannot see this in a trivial way.

Comment: It seems quite easy to me. 
Assume that $\Gamma=\sum a_i \Gamma_i \equiv 0$ for some $a_i\in \mathbb N$ then $D+\Gamma^+\equiv D+\Gamma^-$, which implies the claim.